# Who has any documents that about PostgreSQL background processes?

Tags: postgresql, background, process

Who has any documents that about PostgreSQL background processes?

I'd like to learn the detail about these background processes:

- postgres: logger process
- postgres: writer process
- postgres: wal writer process
- postgres: autovacuum launcher process
- postgres: archiver process
- postgres: stats collector process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick internet search turned up these documents, I find the first one very interesting:

- http://raghavt.blogspot.com/2011/04/postgresql-90-architecture.html
- http://cisc322.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/conceptual_architecture_of_postgresql.pdf
- http://vibhork.blogspot.com/2011/04/postgresqlpostgres-plus-advanced-server.html
- http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql02.html
- https://www.slideshare.net/EnterpriseDB/overviewutilityprocesses-finalaug222013

Comment: I  can only open the second , the first and the third can not open.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/)? In particular the parts about [server administration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/admin.html) and the [internals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/internals.html).

There additionally are some resources [in the wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Database_Administration_and_Maintenance), and not a year passes by without one of the core developers going through one or more of the points you're wondering about at a [PG Conference](http://www.pgcon.org/).

Comment: Thanks,But i don't found  detail about the Backend Processes in the documentation .

Comment: I'd suggest that you look a bit harder. WAL, autovacuum, stats collector, etc. are all described and at the very least outlined. And there's the actual source code if you want the gory details.