# Why are there multiple instances of postgres running in the background after restart?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

Why are there multiple instances of postgres running in the background after restart?

[image]

How can I configure it not to start on booting up the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's perfectly normal.

Postgres uses a multi-process architecture rather than a multi-threaded architecture.

Those are not "multiple instances", but the background processes that Postgres creates during the server startup (because of its multi-process architecture).

See [Who has any documents that about PostgreSQL background processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544088) for more information on the background processes that Postgres starts or [this example processlist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-ps.html) in the manual

[This presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/EnterpriseDB/overviewutilityprocesses-finalaug222013) also gives some insight about the Postgres background processes.